# Do the thread pools created by Executors ever release their memory?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the basic `fixed` thread pool:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MaxListeners)
```

It is my intention to continually submit new tasks - in response to incoming tcp socket service requests.

However it seems that when the `Runnable` code within each task were completed - that the memory they consume were *not* released?  I am seeing continuously growing jvm memory usage.

The application tends to process a set of tasks in groups. We can see a stairstep memory usage pattern: after each set of tasks the memory is a couple of tens of megabytes higher. Waiting even tens of minutes (to hours) does not result in memory being reclaimed.

So two questions:

- Is there a means to reclaim the memory of the `Executors` thread pool ***without shutting the pool down***
- If not, then how can a long-running threadpool be designed using the existing `java.util[.concurrent]` packages?

Comment: problem might be in the way that your application has been implemented. didn't you try to take a heap snapshot and analyze  it (using JProfiler or YourKit)?

Comment: @hunter  I have spent a lot of time with `jvisualvm`  `jstat` etc.

Comment: Runnables should absolutely become eligible for GC once they are done executing. (If the Runnable uses any ThreadLocal storage, that's a different story.) The GC likely won't collect the Runnable immediately, though.

Comment: Executors.newFixedThreadPool returns ThreadPoolExecutor , as far as i know there is no this kind of memory leak in ThreadPoolExecutor . even JBossThreadPoolExecutor is also based on java ThreadPoolExecutor.so i am sure that this is a problem of your application. my suggestion is analyze those kind of object reference to find our the GC roots and then you may realize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Java do not get garbage collected until there are no references left to those objects.  Do not look at this as a thread issue but as an object reference issue.  That is to say, find out what living objects are still referencing that data.

Luckily there are tools to help you with this.  You can use profilers to inspect what objects are still alive and you can even get data about those objects.  Attached is an example of the default profiler in the Netbeans IDE.  It is profiling my application and displaying all living Timeline objects (thats' what I focused in on).  But it could have easily shown me all objects.  This is a quick way of seeing which objects are causing memory leaks or just staying alive too long.

[image]

EDIT:  Please note, @JBNIzet pointed out.

> Objects can be GCed even if there are still references to them. What matters is if there is a chain of strong references to the object from a GC root (thread stack or static variable).

This is very important to note, as most things will never get cleaned up if all references to that object needed to be gone.

Comment: It's probably not what you actually meant, but "until there are no references left to those objects" is plain wrong. Objects *can* be GCed even if there are still references to them. What matters is if there is a chain of string references to the object from a GC root (thread stack or static variable).

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, thanks for clearing that up.  Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPoolExecutor does all necessary cleaning automatically after each task execution. But it only cleans its own memory. Objects created during task execution is responsibility of the programer. If memory grows after tasks executions it means there are references to obects that tasks created or to tasks themselves somewhere in your program.